# How to send messages from terminal to Vim using the JSON API?

Tags: terminal

Vim 8 built-in terminal allows communication to and from a running job. The manual describes a terminal API [`:h terminal-api`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-api) that lets a running job to Vim. An example message is provided to open a file with

```
<Esc>]51;["drop", "README.md"]<07>
```

My question is how to actually send this to Vim from a running bash interactive session or a shell script? If this line has to be typed literally how can one enter the escape codes before and after the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the word job in that doc is that it refers to whatever is running in the `:term` (a shell, gdb, etc.).

You can encode the message in bash with `printf`:

```
printf '<Esc>]51;%s\a' message.
```

Here, the esc sequence is entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work for the message `["drop", "README.md"]` in the example of my question. It just prints the message and a 7 at the end. I tried replacing `\x007` with the bell character `^G` but then it only prints the message.

Comment: If `\x007` is the bell character, then use `\a`

Comment: What finally worked for me is `printf '<Esc>]51;["drop", "README.md"]<CTRL-G>'` where <Esc> and <CTRL-G>` were input followed by `Ctrl`-`V`. Your answer has the bracket after <Esc> the other way `[` which is why probably it was not recognized as the proper escape sequence.

Comment: @SigmaPiEpsilon ive corrected the answer then. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, thanks!